# I am having a IndexError: list index out of range error trying to grab the text from an xml file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am having an error when trying to iterate through the metadata tags from my xml file and grabbing the text from each tag.   The blanks text makes the number of tags smaller than it actually is.  For example: Name="som" the error hits there.  How can I resolve this?

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('manifest-initial.xml')
node = xmldoc.documentElement

itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('MetaData')
for i in range(0, len(itemlist)): 
    if xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('MetaData')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue is None:
       print("None")
    print(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('MetaData')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue)



<MetaData Name="scrid">5211780</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="Abbeviation">HT</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="Partner Due Date">02/21/2019</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="version">1</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="asset">episode</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="psa.orig.providerAssetId">80</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="Publish Date">20.0</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="activationDate">26</MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="som"></MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="cadq"></MetaData>
                        <MetaData Name="cadr"></MetaData>
```

Output from terminal stops at "som".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no child element for your code to evaluate - thus being out of range.  Check to see if the child element exists instead of seeing what value it contains.

Comment: try using the hasChildNodes() function

Comment: You are very welcome.  Please mark it as the answer to "close" the question.